# Problem with launch jupyter notebook in gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook

`Anaconda` is installed in this instance, and the `external ip` has been set as static. Meanwhile, the firewall rule exception for `jupyter notebook` has been added to give:

```
Source IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0
Allowed protocols and ports: tcp:8888
```

and the configuration file `.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py.py` has been edited to add these terms:

```
c = get_config()
c.NotebookApp.ip = '*'
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False
c.NotebookApp.port = <Port Number>
```

However, when I run `jupyter-notebook`, I still receive such information:

```
[I 22:50:31.533 NotebookApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /home/baggiohbs_1989/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 22:50:31.533 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is /home/baggiohbs_1989/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab
[I 22:50:31.538 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/baggiohbs_1989
[I 22:50:31.538 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 22:50:31.538 NotebookApp] http://(tf-with-anaconda1 or 127.0.0.1):8888/?token=5de42e55c4192604f3da19f3cb0d45a24cb0269e1de23f2b
[I 22:50:31.538 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 22:50:31.539 NotebookApp]

    Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
    to login with a token:
        http://(tf-with-anaconda1 or 127.0.0.1):8888/?token=5de42e55c4192604f3da19f3cb0d45a24cb0269e1de23f2b
```

How this could be? I expect to see `jupyter notebook` running on the static external IP. Which part I am wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using any of the marketplace instant set ups?
https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/jetware/pytorch-python-cpu-minilab?q=jupyter&id=7fe71afc-b009-4cb9-a219-5d6d8e7f72c6&project=derivesystems-1&folder&organizationId=839001814545

Comment: no, I am using the free trial.

Answer (score 0):

It should work just fine on external IP address in your case. Do not remember exactly but I think `tf-with-anaconda1` is a DNS record for the instance with the external IP. If you can not access notebook most likely problem in the FireWall rules, you can open port 8888 like this:

```
allow_port () {
     gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-port-$1 --allow tcp:$1
}

allow_port 8888
```

BTW if you are using Deep Learning images `jupyter lab` and `jupyter notebook` already running (on port 8080), you just need to open port 8080 if you want to access it from the Internet.

Comment: I installed anaconda, so that means the `anaconda/jupyter` rather than the original conda is used is used, right? I added the firewall rule already, and I think that is exactly what `Allowed protocols and ports: tcp:8888` does.

Comment: @BsHe depends how have you installed anaconda? and if you are in the Anaconda environment - yes, jupyter from the anaconda is used. What the current status, does it work?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I just downloaded anaconda from the repo and then installed it.